# Image is not displayed in html inside jsp

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am trying to display a image in html in JSP script, just using **img** tag.

**index.jsp** code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="topbar">
    <img src="images/x.png" alt="img" height="30" width="25">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I ma using eclipse neon (apache-tomcat local server in Ubuntu) and my directory structure is :

[image]

When I run **index.jsp** , image is not displayed. What I am doing wrong?

Please ask me if you need more information.

Comment: And if you type in your browser `yourdomain/images/x.png` image is displayed? If not - that is the couse - wrong path

Comment: No, its a **HTTP Status 404** error

Comment: Then what should be the right path?

Comment: Do you use `http://localhost:8080/projectName/index.jsp` to load the JSP, or just `http://localhost:8080/projectName/`? A **general** hint: Use your browser's developer tools to check the URL it uses to (try to) load the image.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek , I tried both URL to load jsp page, none of those work for me

Comment: But it works if I use image **src** as **http://code--projects.com/java.png** , a absolute URL .

Comment: Hm, maybe you should check you deployment folder (if you use standard Eclipse and Tomcat config, it should be `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/projectName`), if the `x.png` has been deployed. Or just try to republish your webapp.

Comment: if image not display, is there any error in webpage console, and browser console?

Comment: @yash , no such error in any console. just inspector in web console shows **could't load this image**

Comment: @JozefChocholacek , the path you mentioned contains only ROOT directory and ROOT directory lists only WEB-INF . How I see if x.png is deployed or not?

Comment: change to <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/x.png" alt="img" height="30" width="25">

Comment: @user3138997 you solved my problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

@user3138997 gave me hints:

I just need to write as:

```
<img src="/projectName/images/x.png" alt="img" height="30" width="25">
```

And this shows the image.

Comment: so bad path just as i thought